# Fetching div class ids inside parent div and turning into an array? Tough Stuff?

Tags: jquery, arrays

So I've been working on this the past 3 days, not too familiar with the .map function. What I'm trying to do is ( find or fetch ) all the ids onclick from a specified class on divs inside of a parent div... Example below:

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <div class="fetch" id="post1" rel="1"></div>
    <div class="fetch" id="post2" rel="2"></div>
    <div class="fetch" id="post3" rel="3"></div>
    <div class="fetch" id="post4" rel="4"></div>
    <div class="fetch" id="post5" rel="5"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the function I've coded so far... it does work and finds ids inside the div "parentDiv" but after it finds the div the function stops. I'm certain than an array would work for this. Basically, When a user click a link, .attr(id) is fetched from that link and a div is opened up inside the "parentDiv" and when a user clicks another link... I want the script to check if that ID# has already been used ( find all ids inside parentDiv and check against them ).

```
var arr = $(".fetch [rel]").map(function() {
    if ( id == arr ) {
        console.log( arr );
        $createDiv = 'nope';
    } else {
        $createDiv = 'yup';
    }
    return this.id;
});
```

I've also coded this little piece that still doesn't work right:

```
$("div.fetch").each(function(id, value) {
console.log('div.fetch' + id + ':' + $(this).attr('rel'));
var statusId = $(this).attr('rel').serializeArray();
alert(statusId);

        if ( $.inArray( id , statusID ) ) {
            $createTab = 'nope';

        } else {
            $createTab = 'yup';
        }
});
```

The problem I'm having is its not blocking the id#s the .map function finds... Not switching back to it and prevents other new id#s from being opened.

I hope I provided enough info on explaining my problem.

I've updated the structure the same way I have coded it on my site.

Comment: I have a function that opens new divs inside the #parentDiv and I'm trying to check agains divs with class="fetch" if that id# has already been opened and if so select that id#, if not open a new div with class="fetch" and corresponding id#.

Comment: You keep on resetting the value of `$createDiv` for every step in the loop. Is this the intended result?

Comment: Yup... If the id# is in the array, then it shouldn't open a new div and highlight that id# that is open... if not, then it creates a new div inside the #parentDiv with class="fetch" id="6" or something!

Comment: How does it do that? It seems that you're *really* not familiar with the `.map` function! http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

Comment: I want to keep this as quick and as simple as possible. I think the .each command may work best here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but ***maybe*** I did get it:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <div class="fetch" id="post346">asdf</div>
    <div class="fetch" id="post21">asdf</div>
    <div class="fetch" id="post471">asdf</div>
    <div class="fetch" id="post32">asdf</div>
    <div class="fetch" id="post178">asdf</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var regex = /\d+$/,
    IDs = $('#parentDiv .fetch').toArray().map(function(e){
        return parseInt(e.id.match(regex));
    });

// now let's say you want to add these divs: 346 ,232, 178
var divsToCreate = [346,232,178];

$.each(divsToCreate, function(i,e)
{
    if ( $.inArray(e, IDs) != -1 )
        $('#post' + e).addClass('selected');
    else
        $('#parentDiv').append($('<div />', {
            class: 'fetch',
            id: 'post' + e,
            text: e
        }));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QGRrs/6/

**Note:** IDs cannot start with a number: http://css-tricks.com/28-ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/

Comment: I would never suggest it in practice, but it works in FF and Chrome(just tried it), I'm assuming older browsers like IE6 choke? (<- About the id's starting with numbers)

Comment: hmm ya it definitely is there, and I believe it should be cause that would be horrible practice. But fact remains you can infact do it error free in FF and Chrome(Didn't test any others).

Comment: Yup! I don't care about IE6... In fact Im blocking users using IE6... It's 2011 for pete's sake! :) And it does work it IE7 and IE8!

Comment: @Brandon Lee: I've updated my answer to reflect your changes. Also, just because "it works" does not mean you should use it. It's against the spec.

Comment: Thanks joseph for your help. I know its against spec. but I can't figure out any other way to achieve this without using the rel... actually... can't i just strip out the word post out of the div id# in the jquery function to fetch the ids? Possible?

Comment: @Brandon Lee: You sure can. Updated my answer.

Comment: Hey Joseph... thanks so much for your help... so click on links are writing to array, but as 0,1,2,3,4 and not the actual id# of the post? Your function looks like it may solve my issue! YAY! I've updated the .fetch ids to reflect what I mean... Sorry I didn't provide that info earlier... my bad.

Comment: Not sure the array is needed however if you do go with this code currently the array returned will not work past 9 it will go 7,8,9,0,1,2,3...7,8,9,0,1,2,3 etc... Instead of substr I suggest: `return /^[a-zA-Z]*([0-9]+)$/.exec(e.id)[0];` Perhaps store the regex outside of the function so it doesn't get recompiled everytime as well.

Comment: @All: I have updated my answer with a regex, so that you can have more than 9 posts.

Comment: Finally... It's almost embarassing how BAD I struggled with this! Thanks again Joseph... Works perfect! And it meets the spec. No more rel="" in div. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var getDivIDS = function(papadiv) {
    var div_ids = [];
    papadiv.find('>div').each(function() {
        div_ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });
    return div_ids;
}

var mydivids = getDivIDS($('#parentdiv'));
```

If I understood your question correctly that will return a list of ids of all first-children divs inside a element.

However I don't quite fully understand your explanation of your goal, and I feel there's probably a better solution than doing it this way.

**Edit:**
Ok so if I understand this right:

```
var doAction(id) {
    $('#parentDiv div.selected').removeClass('selected'); //If using a selected class else ignore this line
    if ($('#'+id).length) {
        $('#'+id).addClass('selected'); //or .show() or .highlight() found it as existing
    } else {
        $('#parentDiv').append($('<div><\/div>', {'class': 'fetch', id: id})); //Not found make a new one
    }
}

//Inside click or wherever
doAction(id_to_look_for);
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks dennmat. I have this div id="parentDiv"... I want to be able to open multiple divs with class="fetch" id="?" inside of "parentDiv". onclick of a link to open new div, I need to check if that id# already exists ( been opened ) and if so, make that div selected... if not, then open that NEW div. This is a complicated task for me. :(

Comment: Updated my post, hopefully it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Hey dennmat, how would update that last function you posted to work with the rel attribute?

Comment: Not sure how you mean, something like? `$('a.someclass').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); doAction($(this).attr('rel');});` I'm assuming you meant the rel attribute set on the anchor?

Comment: nope Im using the rel attribute off of the div to check against ids! :) it does work... not kosher?

Comment: I see then instead of `$('#'+id)` it would be `$('div[rel='+id+']')`. Not sure about the kosherness you'd have to check with w3.